Userform Validation
I am trying to create a userform with 7 textboxes wherein each answer to the textboxes will be placed into the different columns on another sheet "Bulk Loader". I need to have a code added to my existing code wherein if one of the textboxes between textbox 1 to textbox 5 is not filled in, the answers will not be submitted to sheet 2. Here's the existing code that I have.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bulk Loader")
Dim n As Long

n = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
sh.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = TextBox2.Value
sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = TextBox3.Value
sh.Range("D" & n + 1).Value = TextBox4.Value
sh.Range("E" & n + 1).Value = TextBox5.Value
sh.Range("F" & n + 1).Value = TextBox6.Value
sh.Range("G" & n + 1).Value = TextBox7.Value

 If TextBox1.Value <> "" And TextBox2.Value <> "" And TextBox3.Value <> "" And TextBox4.Value <> "" And TextBox5.Value <> "" And TextBox6.Value <> "" And TextBox7.Value <> "" Then
    
    MsgBox "IPO Details Added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "ERROR"
    
    Unload Me
    
    Exit Sub
    
    End If
    
    If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "User ID can't be filled blank", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "ERROR"
        
    End If
    
    If TextBox2.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Launch Date", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "ERROR"
        
    End If
    
    If TextBox3.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please input Date", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "ERROR"
        
    End If
    
    If TextBox4.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please input Price", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "ERROR"
        
    End If
    
    If TextBox5.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Launch Price ", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "ERROR"
        
    End If
       
    Exit Sub
    
    If response = "vbOKOnly" Then DATA_ENTRY.Show
    
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub


You're populating the worksheet before testing for empty values?

It's nicer for the user if you tell them everything that's missing and not one by one.
For example:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, msg As String
    
    'check for any empty required fields
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - User ID"
    If Len(TextBox2.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Launch Date"
    If Len(TextBox3.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Date"
    If Len(TextBox4.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Price"
    If Len(TextBox5.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Launch Price"
    
    If Len(msg) > 0 Then 'anything missing?
        MsgBox "The following fields are required:" & msg, _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Information"
    Else
        'OK to write to sheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bulk Loader")
        With sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Resize(1, 7).Value = Array(TextBox1.Value, TextBox2.Value, _
                                  TextBox3.Value, TextBox4.Value, TextBox5.Value, _
                                  TextBox6.Value, TextBox7.Value)
        
        End With
    End If
End Sub


Hello the code is working, however an error message saying out of memory shows up? Is there a way to resolve this?

I can't see anything in the code that might trigger that - did you make any changes?  Do you have any event code in the code module for "Bulk Loader"?  Maybe try stepping through the code and see where the problem is.

I guess this is because of several files open on my excel. I had tried to close everything and the issue is now resolved. Thank you!

No problem.  Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.
